# How do I fix this foreach loop variable syntax error?

Tags: foreach, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to use `foreach` in SystemVerilog.  What I am doing wrong here?

```
`define size 3:0 //variable

module tb;
  reg [7:0] temp;
  initial begin
    temp=8'd25;
    $display("%d",temp[`size]);
    foreach((temp[`size])[i])
      $display("%d",temp[i]);
    (temp[`size])[i]=1'b0;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You want can put a condition inside the foreach loop

```
foreach(temp[i])
       if (i inside {[`size]})
          $display("%d",temp[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is incorrect for the `foreach`.  You just want to use `[i]`.

```
`define size 3:0 //variable

module tb;
  reg [7:0] temp;
  initial begin
    temp=8'd25;
    $display("%d",temp[`size]);
    foreach(temp[i])
      $display("%d",temp[i]);
  end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
 9
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
```

Comment: i want to loop around the temp[`size] only not the whole temp bus